# Knowing the final recipients & message with 'MFMessageComposeViewController'?

Tags: ios, sms

I have a few questions regarding `MFMessageComposeViewController`:

1. Is there a way to know to whom the user actually sent the SMS to?
   Or, at least be able to know to how many numbers the SMS was sent to?
2. What was the message that was actually sent?

Here is what I have so far, and it works OK. But It seems there is only one delegate, but it's so simple that it's pretty much useless.

```
- (void)showSMS:(NSArray *)numbers message:(NSString *)message {

        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [messageController setRecipients:numbers];
        [messageController setBody:message];

        [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result {

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled) {

        NSLog(@"SMS cancelled");
    }
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultFailed) {

        NSLog(@"SMS failed");
    }
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent) {

        NSLog(@"SMS sent");
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The iOS SDK doesn't expose a way to access this.

From Apple's documentation of [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html):

> Important: The message composition interface itself is not
>   customizable and must not be modified by your app. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your app is unable to make further changes
>   to the message content. The user can edit the content using the
>   interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set
>   the values of content fields, if desired, before presenting the
>   interface.

Comment: I'm not looking to change anything after creation, but to get a real result. :/